# MDPI 'mybib' not working for variant A

Tags: bibtex, winedt

mybib reference is not yet working after going through all previously suggested solutions by other people on stackexchange. I will prefer to use 'mybib' for variant A as I have over 50 references in total. I use WinEdt to type my work. I will be glad if this issue can be fixed.

Here is my mdpi tex file

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthor]{Definitions/mdpi}

\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}

   %=================================================================
  \firstpage{1}
    \makeatletter
    \setcounter{page}{\@firstpage}
    \makeatother
    \pubvolume{xx}
    \issuenum{1}
     \articlenumber{5}
      \pubyear{2020}
      \copyrightyear{2020}
     \history{Received: date; Accepted: date; Published: date}

    \Title{ $LU$ factorization and $WZ$ factorization }


   \newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0002} 
  \Author{Ola B.I. $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}}
  \AuthorNames{Ola B.I. }
  \address{$^{1}$ \quad Department of }

 \abstract{  $WZ$ factorization and $LU$ factorization ...}

\keyword{  $WZ$ factorization; $LU$ factorization}

\MSC{65F05}

   \begin{document}

   \section{Introduction}
  $WZ$ factorization was coined by  Evans and Hatzopoulos  \cite{Evans1979}.  The factorization breaks matrices into block forms \cite{Huang2010,Heinig2005}.


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \reftitle{References}

   %%\section*{References}

      %=====================================
     % References, variant A: external bibliography
     %=====================================
      %\externalbibliography{yes}
      %\bibliography{your_external_BibTeX_file}
     %\externalbibliography{mdpi}
      %%\bibliographystyle{mdpi}
      %\bibliography{mybib}

      \end{document}
```

Here is mybib reference

```
    @article{Evans1979,
    author = {Evans, D. and Hatzopoulos, M.},
     title = {A parallel linear system solver},
     journal = {Int. J. Comput. Math.},
      volume = {7},
       number = {3},
       pages = {227-238},
        year = {1979},
        type = {Journal Article}
         }

       @inproceedings{Huang2010,
        author = {Huang, P. and MacKay, A. and Teng, D.},
         title = {A hardware/software codesign of WZ factorization to improve time to solve matrices},
         booktitle = {Canadian Conference on Electrical and Computer Engineering},
         publisher = {IEEE},
         year = {2010},
         pages = {1-5},
          type = {Conference Proceedings}
          }

    @inbook{Heinig2005,
     author = {Heinig, G. and Rost, K.},
      title = {Schur-type algorithms for the solution of Hermitian  Toeplitz systems via factorization},
      booktitle = {Recent advances in operator theory and its applications},
      publisher = {Springer},
      pages = {233-252},
       year = {2005},
      type = {Book Section}
      }
```

Comment: In what sense it does not work. The MWE works for me when the bibliography part contains only `\bibliography{mybib}`.  It should not contain `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: Every step I took to correct the error is not fruitful. I will suggest you help me run the bib in the tex to see the error. thanks

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.